# Usage of “in” vs. “within”?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing about activity happening inside an organization. Should I use the word *in* or *within* their organization?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the context.

Comment: You might also be interested in checking out [our sister-site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The two words are synonymous; that being the case, it is a matter of preference.

That being said, I feel *within* has more audible appeal. For instance:

> The activities carried out within the organization appeared most sinister.

As opposed to:

> The activities carried out in the organization appeared most sinister.

Comment: Those two sentences imply different things to me. "carried from within" implies that the organisation is carrying out *external* activities; "carried out in" implies *internal* activities.

Comment: If you'll notice the sentence says "carried _out_ from within..." which is synonymous to "carried out in"

Comment: Yes, I omitted "out" by mistake. No, I do not agree that it is synonymous to "carried out in". It's the word "from" which (to me) implies *external* activities.

Comment: Okay, I can see your point now. I'll edit accordingly.